# Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have an old project, I import this project in my Android studio, i am getting this error.
Yes I searched for it from internet and i found many solutions for that,but non of them solved my issue.

**Here is my build.gradle file**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.


buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Here is My module level build.gradle**
 here is my build.gradle which is under app>src>build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.pedrocarrillo.expensetracker"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 3
    versionName "1.2"
}

signingConfigs {
    release {
        def Properties localProps = new Properties()
        localProps.load(new FileInputStream(file('../local.properties')))
        storeFile file("tracker_expense.jks")
        storePassword localProps["storePass"]
        keyAlias localProps["alias"]
        keyPassword localProps["pass"]
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

repositories {
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.82.2'
compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.1.4'
}
```

Comment: is this project level build file or module level build file?

Comment: @BaneeIshaqueK i dont know its under Gradle Scripts. there also a build.gradle under app>src>build.gradle

Comment: So, this is project level build file and other is module level build file, can you paste other build.gradle file contents?

Comment: @BaneeIshaqueK i have updated the question with module level build file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This : **Project Level Gradle File**...

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.


buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }   
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Module Level Gradle File**...

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pedrocarrillo.expensetracker"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.2"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            def Properties localProps = new Properties()
            localProps.load(new FileInputStream(file('../local.properties')))
            storeFile file("tracker_expense.jks")
            storePassword localProps["storePass"]
            keyAlias localProps["alias"]
            keyPassword localProps["pass"]
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
    compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.82.2'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.1.4'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your **top-level file** you have **to remove** this line:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```